# Error copying configuration files from Tomcat to Project directory: Directory is invalid /opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, config, tomcat9

Have a newly installed Tomcat-9, I'm trying to run a project with IntelliJ IDEA, It throws an error `Directory is invalid` saying:

`Error running 'Tomcat 9.0.40': Error copying configuration files from /opt/apache-tomcat-9/conf to /home/saad/.IntelliJIdea2019.3/system/tomcat/Tomcat_9_0_40_CS_IS_1_20170212_Assignment1/conf: Directory is invalid /opt/apache-tomcat-9/conf/Catalina`

I made sure that both directories mentioned in error exist, What is the problem here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked permissions on a directories?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced such situation `Directory is invalid /opt/apache-tomcat-9/conf/Catalina`. So what I did is basically I remove all tomcat apt packages

> `sudo apt remove --purge tomcat9 tomcat9-docs` 
> `sudo apt autoremove` 
> `sudo apt autoclean`

After that I download tomcat9 binary [link](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi) and extract it and create a soft link for easy use

> `sudo tar -xvf ~/Downloads/<binary-name> -C /usr/local` 
> `cd /usr/local` 
> `sudo ln -s <tomcat-9-directory-name> tomcat9`

change the mod of the `tomcat9` directory

> `sudo chmod -R 777 tomcat9/`

Then goto intelliJ and navigate`File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Application Servers`. Remove tomcat settings if available(minus icon). Then add new Tomcat server by pressing plus icon. Set Tomcat home path as`/usr/local/tomcat9` and press ok.

[image]

Once you finished it, open the configuration dialog `Run > Edit Configurations` and remove Tomcat servers if there any. And Press plus icon and select Tomcat Server. Then goto the Deployment tab and press plus sign and add the artifact that you want to deploy. Then press ok and re-run the application.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, all I did was change some permissions:

`sudo chmod +rx /usr/share/tomcat10/conf/Catalina`

Though that might just be a temporary solution, I'm not sure.